# How to dissolve faces after joining objects

Tags: objects, faces, edges

How to dissolve faces after joining objects,I mean How to remove edges between two faces after joining their objects?

Comment: `tab` into edit mode then press `a` then press `m` *> merge by distance*

Comment: That doesn't work!

Comment: can you please provide more details or screenshots to clarify your problem?